# ¿Cómo enviar un formulario a una pagina externa utilizando C# ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy tratando de enviar datos desde un formulario a una página web externa, pero después de enviarlos apareceria una página de "Gracias por contactarnos".

```
 <form action="~/Home/SendForm/" method="POST" class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="form-label" for="first_name">first_name: </label>
                <input class="form-control mb-3" id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" required size="20" type="text" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="form-label" for="last_name">last_name: </label>
                <input class="form-control mb-3" id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" required size="20" type="text" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="form-label" for="mobile">mobile: </label>
                <input class="form-control mb-3" id="mobile" maxlength="40" name="mobile" required size="20" type="text" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="form-label" for="email">email: </label>
                <input class="form-control mb-3" id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" required size="20" type="text" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <label class="form-label" for="company">company: </label>
                <input class="form-control mb-3" id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" required size="20" type="text" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 buttonSubmit">
                <input class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="Gracias()">
            </div>
        </form>
```

Con esto estoy enviando los datos al controlador, pero debe ir a otra página web (ej: http://web.ReciveData.com/)

Intenté enviar el formulario a la pagina web asi:

```
<form action="http://web.ReciveData.com/" method="POST" class="row">
```

Boton submit con funcion "Gracias()":

```
<input class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="Gracias()">
```

Javascript:

```
function Thanks() {
    window.location.href("http://web.MyWebPage.com/Home/Gracias")
}
```

Pero no funciona. Basicamente lo que intento hacer es cargar los datos, enviarlos a la pagina web externa, y que se muestra una pagina web que yo cree para agradecer el contacto.

No se me ocurre absolutamente nada, y lo que encontré por internet son mas que nada ejemplos basicos.

**ACTUALIZACION**

Despues de tener problemas CORS, pude configurar el proyecto en el Program.cs, y ahora lko estoy intentando asi:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let formularioDEC = document.getElementById('formDEC');
    formularioDEC.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

    let formularioSAC = document.getElementById('formSAC');
    formularioSAC.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

    let formularioLFD = document.getElementById('formLFD');
    formularioLFD.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

    async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const form = new FormData(this);
        const response = await fetch(this.action, {
            mode: "no-cors",
            method: this.method,
            body: form,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        console.log(this.method);
        console.log(form);

        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('OK');
            this.reset();
            await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res({ ok: window.location.href = 'https://myWeb.com.ar/Home/Gracias' }), 2000));
        } else {
            console.log(response);
            console.log('Not OK');
        }
    };
});
```

Si no tengo el Javascript, el formulario se envia correctamente, pero me redirige a una web externa. Yo lo que quiero y estoy tratando de hacer es redireccionarlo a una web customizada luego de hacer el submit.

Para eso estoy usando `await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res({ ok: window.location.href = 'https://smyWeb.com.ar/Home/Gracias' }), 2000));` pero estoy recibiendo un `response.ok === false`, y nosé porqué.

Son 3 formularios distintos en la misma vista.

Comment: Mira el código de esta publicación https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/564295/301324 Si bien la pregunta es otra cosa, el código hace exactamente lo que tú quieres. En la parte donde existe un alert, ahí deberías poner tu función Thanks()

Comment: Ahora lo veo @Yussef, gracias!

Comment: Estuve probando el código y no está llegando a la funcion, puse varios console.log y no está pasando por ahi.

Comment: @Yussef estoy teniendo los isguientes errores: `has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.,`

Comment: Y este: `site.js?v=d1NEHlcNIoUrjhoqBxNIg18ZEihTRiUMiR_BbUrQqL4:41                  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at HTMLFormElement.handleSubmit`

Comment: Si recibes error de CORS, es que no vas a poder envía el form a esa página externa de esta manera y de ninguna otra que implique un navegador

Comment: Osea basicamente no voy a poder enviar el formulario de ninguna manera?

Comment: Si es el error que yo pienso que es no podrás desde el navegador. La solución es que si tú tienes acceso a ese servidor lo configures para que permita solicitudes externas o al menos desde el sitio que envía el formulario. Si no tienes acceso, la solución es enviar el formulario a tu servidor y desde tu servidor enviar el form al otro servidor, ya que el bloqueo de CORS lo realiza el navegador, pero entre servidores no habría problema

Comment: El servidor externo es de Salesforce, por lo que deberia intentar hacer lo segundo